# Transform img src to a href

Tags: php, regex, image, lightbox

I need some help to get this working in PHP.

I have a lot of information and pictures in different "pages" in wordpress. Now I can't really figure out how I should manage to solve this problem.

I have alot of images like this directly in the "page text"

```
<img src="..." />
```

And I need to replace that so it becomes

```
<a href="content of img src" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="..." /></a>
```

I think there is some way to fix this with some regexp which I know close to nothing about.

Thanks in advance, even if you can't solve the problem you perhaps can point me in the right direction. There can be up to 4-5 images in a "page".

Comment: <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
   <?php endwhile;?>
  <?php endif;?> So the images contains inside of the_content();

Comment: You can inject a javascript to do that easily. It would fit? But I need to know what is this: `content of img src`

Comment: <img src="mypicutrelink" /> should become <a href="mypicturelink" data-lightbox="image-1"><img src="mypicturelink" /></a>   So my the_content(); contains <img src="mypicutrelink" /> from start. and its from that I want to add a <a> before with data-lightbox1 and the href to be the same as the img src.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP DOMDocument for this. Using a regular expression could also work, but you will have better success using this method.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html); // $html is your "page text"

//Create new wrapper
$new_anchor = $dom->createElement('a');
$new_anchor->setAttribute('data-lightbox','image-1');

//Find all images
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

//Iterate though images
foreach ($images AS $image) {
    //Clone our created anchor
    $new_anchor_clone = $new_anchor->cloneNode();
    //Add on the src
    $new_anchor_clone->setAttribute('href',$image->getAttribute('src'));
    //Replace image with this anchor
    $image->parentNode->replaceChild($new_anchor_clone,$image);
    //Append this image to wrapper anchor
    $new_anchor_clone->appendChild($image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I said in your comment there are a few things that you can do to solve this. I will show how you can do with a **Regular Expression** which obviously you will have to improve to fit to your problem. In order to use a regular expression you will have to be sure about the pattern that you want to replace, because if any one of the `img` tag doesn't match your pattern, theese one will not be replaced. So I made this little example:

```
$content = "
<html>
  <body>
    <img src='myImg.jpg'/><br/>
    <img src='myImg2.jpg'/><br/>
    <img src='myImg3.jpg'/><br/>
    <img src='myImg4.jpg'/><br/>
    <img src='myImg5.jpg'/><br/>
    <img src='myImg6.jpg'/><br/>
  </body>
</html>
";

$newContent = preg_replace( "/(<img src=')([^']*)('\/>)/", "<a href='$2'>$1$2$3</a>", $content);
echo $newContent;
```

As you can see in my `$content` variable the `img` tags follow the same pattern which make it easier to create a R.E.

`"/(<img src=')([^']*)('\/>)/"` the parentesis identify groups (used to replace latter) first pattern identify the `<img src='`, the second part `([^']*)` I'm saying: everithing that is not a sigle quote and the third part I start from the closing quote `('\/>)` to the closing tag img.

Every parentesis means a group that internaly receive a number counting from left to right, so:

```
(<img src=') group 1
([^']*) group 2
('\/>) group 3
```

In a img tag as this: `<img src='myImg3.jpg'/>` it would be:

```
group 1 = <img src='
group 2 = myImg3.jpg
group 3 = '/>
```

This groups are named as `$n` for the `preg_replace` command as states the documentation: [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

So I then replace for `"<a href='$2'>$1$2$3</a>"` which is self explanatory.

And in order to you learn and test your regular expressions use this [Site](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) I like it because you can paste your text and create your pattern and see what happens on the fly. If your pattern match it will show the occurrences with a blue background.

So, let me know if it helps you. And sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Hey, very nice of you to make this. I was away for a few days and will take a look at this. Thank you very mutch for the help! :)

Comment: @user2957788 glad to help and hope it helps you :)